# Find DataGrid Column and Row Index based on cell value of column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable, defaultview

I need to do the following with a DataGrid.  E.g.

```
Col A       Col B
1           A           
2           B
3           C
4           D
```

For instance where Col A = 3.  I then want to change the background cell.Background = some color where row 3 intersects Col B.  I would be passing in the value for Col A and column name dynamically.  I am returning the cell values from a DataTable where the DataGrid is bound to a defaultview of the DataTable. Col A is the unique key.

Comment: can you give more explanation of what are you trying to achieve?Do you want to change the color of a cell?

Comment: I am comparing two DataTables that are bound to DataGrids (same table structure).  I am comparing cell by cell for differences.  I want to change the cell color on cells that have differences in the DataGrid; not the entire row.  I am able to identify the cells in the DataTable's with differences; then based on the unique key I want to hit that row then intersect on the column header and only update that cell where the row and column header match.

Comment: Or is there any way to highlight the cell in the DataTable and refresh the view on the dataGrid?  I don't see any properties on the DataTable to handle this.  DT.Rows[i]["Col_ID"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution with a single line of code to pragmatically set the current cell based on the items and column index for anyone else who may be looking for a solution to this as well.

In the XAML ensure the SelectionUnit is set to cell. Then:

```
dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[0],dg.Columns[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna change your cell style - use the cell style and Style.DataTrigger. you just have to make sure that the data you need is anywhere in the DataRow.